# Getting HTML out of selection / range from a web page in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul, firefox-3

I currently using the following the get the selected text from a webpage into a custom firefox extension:

```
getSelectedText: function(){
    var textWindow = document.commandDispatcher.focusedWindow;
    var text = textWindow.getSelection();      
    if (text == null) {text =' ';}
    text = text.toString();
    text = text.replace(/^\s*$/ , "");
    text = text.replace(/\r/g, "\r");
    text = text.replace(/\n/g, "\n");
    text = text.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g , " ");
    text = text.replace(new RegExp(/\u2019/g), "'");
    text = text.replace(new RegExp(/\u201A/g), ",");
    text = text.replace(new RegExp(/\u201B/g), "'");
    return {str:text};
}
```

This works just fine for plain text.

My problem is that i want all the elements of the webpage copied as well ( kind of like the webclips feature in safari )

**Use case -** If the user selects through a webpage with formatted text and images, I want the underlying HTML to get copied as well, so that I can accurately paste it into another XUL window - even send the contents as a rich HTML email if I so wish.

Any pointers?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how do you propose to deal with stylesheets?

Comment: @Joel : I dont think you can get the stylesheet out , ie, you just capture the Html and that's it.

Comment: But any linked resources (images, css, etc.) will have to resolved if you want the display to be at all representative.

Comment: @Joel - check this out - http://manish-chaks.livejournal.com/103700.html

Comment: Ah, I see your `absolutifyUrlsInNode` function. But how does `n.setAttribute(a, n[a]);` do the trick?

Comment: I am not exactly sure. I believe I saw an example on MDC and developed my stuff on top of it

Answer (score 9):

Try using this code:

```
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var content = range.cloneContents();
```

After this code is executed, `content` will be a document fragment that contains a copy of the select DOM nodes.  Note that event listeners will not be cloned.  For more information go to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range.cloneContents